# I am trying to join 2 GP10 tables in a query (SOP10100 & SOP10200)

Tags: sql

I keep getting the following error

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'SOPNUMBE'.
```

Can someone point out my mistake?  This is my first time using inner join.

My code is as follows:

```
Select SOPNUMBE, SOPTYPE, DOCDATE,
ORDRDATE, CMPNTSEQ, ITEMNMBR, QUANTITY,
UNITCOST, UNITPRCE, EXTDCOST, XTNDPRCE
From SOP10100
INNER JOIN SOPNUMBE
On SOP10100.SOPNUMBE = SOP10200.SOPNUMBE
```

Comment: You don't have a table named `SOPNUMBE` by the sound of it

Comment: Use `From    SOP10100 INNER JOIN SOP10200`

Comment: Your second table name is "SOP10200" i guess  but you are using "SOPNUMBE" .

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you are joining a  non existent table..further please use aliases for readabilty..

```
Select  s1.SOPNUMBE, SOPTYPE, DOCDATE, ORDRDATE, CMPNTSEQ, ITEMNMBR, QUANTITY, UNITCOST, UNITPRCE, EXTDCOST, XTNDPRCE
From    SOP10100 s1
INNER JOIN SOPNUMBE s2
On      s1.SOPNUMBE = s2.SOPNUMBE
```

your version should go like this..

```
Select  SOPNUMBE, SOPTYPE, DOCDATE, ORDRDATE, CMPNTSEQ, ITEMNMBR, QUANTITY, UNITCOST, UNITPRCE, EXTDCOST, XTNDPRCE
From    SOP10100
INNER JOIN SOPNUMBE
On      SOP10100.SOPNUMBE = SOPNUMBE.SOPNUMBE
```

Comment: The two aliases used in the first query are the same (both are named `s1`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
Select  SOPNUMBE, SOPTYPE, DOCDATE, ORDRDATE, CMPNTSEQ, ITEMNMBR, QUANTITY, UNITCOST, UNITPRCE, EXTDCOST, XTNDPRCE
From    SOP10100
INNER JOIN SOP10200
On      SOP10100.SOPNUMBE = SOP10200.SOPNUMBE
```